# iTunes Season Pass downloading both HD and SD version of a TV Show

Tags: itunes, hdtv, hdvideo, itunes-store

I purchased a TV Show season pass on the iTunes Store for the HD version of a show.

It started downloading immediately, which is great - however, it also decided that I would want the SD versions as well?!

Why? Is this normal? Does iTunes always bundle the SD versions when you buy HD versions? How can I stop iTunes from trying to download the SD version each time I open it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal - the SD version is for the iPod/iPhone (smaller file size).  AFAIK there is no option to prevent download of the SD version.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior has changed.

- Open the download window
- stop/hold the downloads you want to delete.
- Select all the downloads you wish to delete.
- right click on one of them, choose `delete`.

The downloads will disappear from the list. It is necessary to stop the download before deleting it. Otherwise, choosing `delete` will just stop the download.

This will prevent iTunes from loading the SD versions on startup, however, you need to follow this procedure for every new purchase of a season pass.

If you want to download the SD version later, you can do that by simply searching for available downloads.